# Unable to import otbApplication (Orfeotoolbox) through Python

Tags: python, orfeo-toolbox, otb-applications

I have been trying to import otbApplication through python but it doesn't work even after trying everything I've found online related to this issue.

I created a Python 3.7 environnement, installed numpy and spyder and then ran this in the anaconda prompt console :

```
(base) C:\Users\olive>conda activate myenv

(myenv) C:\Users\olive>call C:\OTB-8.1.2-Win64\otbenv.bat

(myenv) C:\Users\olive>spyder
```

Then I get this when I try to import otbApplication in spyder :

```
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 7.31.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

import otbApplication
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\olive\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_1944\644666572.py", line 1, in <module>
    import otbApplication

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'otbApplication'.
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was the problem if anyone has the same issue.
After calling the otbenv.bat in anaconda prompt, I simply had to modify the current directory of spyder to where the otbApplication.py is stored. In my case I had to run these lines of code and it worked :

```
import os

directory = r"C:\OTB-8.1.2-Win64\lib\python"
os.chdir(directory)

import otbApplication
```